# how to find the layout page in my wordpress website

Tags: noindex

I'm working on a wordpress blog, and I can't find the main page, I want to change the fact that the posts only displayed on 2/3 of the screen but I can't find how... I'm using alison theme.
I found the way to edit pages but I can't really find the index page, I tried to edit some pages but nothing change in the website...

Comment: Are you displaying a list of posts on the front page? Then there most likely isn't a editable page for this but you'll need to change it via the Theme settings (if available)

Comment: @kero I didn't find the option to edit it but the blog owner told me that it used to be on the screen but it changed a while ago and now he don't know how to get it back...

Comment: @kero and yes, I'm pretty sure I'm displaying list of posts